# Ggplot2 seq.default and legend problems

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm working on this df:

```
Col0 <- c("AA", "BB", "CC", "DD","EE","FF")
Col1 <- c(2,2,2,6,1,NA)
Col2 <- c(2,2,2,1,3,NA)
Col3 <- c(2,2,3,4,6,NA)
Col4 <- c(2,2,3,1,2,NA)
Col5 <- c(2,1,1,1,1,NA)
Col6 <- c(2,4,2,5,4,NA)
Col7 <- c(2,4,2,5,4,NA)
Col8 <- c(2,2,3,4,5,NA)
Col9 <- c(1,3,3,2,2,NA)
df<-data.frame(Col0,Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5,Col6,Col7,Col8,Col9)
```

And I created a function that set a colour for each element of the Col0, to manage better the loop:

```
formula <- colnames(df)[1]
nr<- nrow(df)
myColors <- brewer.pal(nr,"Set1")
names(myColors) <- levels(df$Col0)
colScale <- scale_colour_manual(name = "Col0",values = myColors)
```

And the loop is to print a graph for each element of Col0

```
plots<-list()
for(i in 1:nr){
af<- df[i,]
f<- melt(af,id =c("Col0"))
pl<- ggplot(f, aes(variable, value, colour = Col0)) + geom_point()+ colScale}
plots[[i]]<-pl
}
do.call("grid.arrange", c(plots))
```

The problem is that this function works only if in the df there are no NA. In the df proposed, it gives me the error:

```
Error in seq.default(from = best$lmin, to = best$lmax, by = best$lstep) : 'from' deve avere lunghezza 1
```

The other thing i'd like to know is if is possible to create an unique legend for all the graphs, in order to save space and have bigger graphs.
I cannot use facet to solve this problem.

Comment: "I cannot use facet to solve this problem." Why can't you? It seems like the obvious solution.

Comment: Because the project leaders told me not to use it, and besides that, it is all inserted in a markdown file, and even if the function was correctly written ( the plots were printed correctly in R) when i put them into the markdown weren't read as if markdown doesn't accept the facets

Comment: Well, you are free to go the hard way. But I would focus on fixing your issue with the markdown.